# How to select consecutive dates from min and max dates grouped by an ID? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
Old Table:
ID   Min_date     Max_date
A1 | 1-Jan-2000 | 3-Jan-2000
A2 | 8-Jan-2001 | 21-Jan-2000
A3 | 6-Jan-2001 | 18-Jan-2000
```

I want to expand out this table such that I have the consecutive days between each date sorted by the IDs, i.e:

```
New Table:
ID   Date
A1 | 1-Jan-2000
A1 | 2-Jan-2000
A1 | 3-Jan-2000
A2 | 8-Jan-2001
A2 | 9-Jan-2001
```

I am currently doing this in Python however if there is a nice SQL solution that would be preferable.

Thanks

Comment: the suggested duplicate didn't have a recursive cte answer :(   I added one

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code